# Is there a way I can split a huge CSV files into multiple PDF?

Tags: python, windows, pandas, read.csv

I'm trying to split a big CSV files into several smaller PDF files. Need some help on generating the PDFs.

I can split it into multiple CSV or html files. But not sure if there's a way to convert dataframe directly to PDF or convert HTML to PDF. Here's where I am

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\ZhangZ01\Desktop\test\NT_combine.csv'
csv = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col= None, header=0)
## Split data by "CUSTOMER_ID"
for i, g in df.groupby('CUSTOMER_ID'):
    g.to_html(r'C:\Users\ZhangZ01\Desktop\test\{}.html'.format(i), header=True, index_names = False)
```

I did some search online and some people say I could use pdfKit but seems that is not available for Windows user.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Hi! I don't have a windows computer to try, but did you try pypdf ? Do you absolutely need to convert from html ?

Comment: Hi Bastien, as long as I can get PDFs, it doesn't have to be converting from html. csv or dataframe directly to PDF are perfect as well

Comment: you can install wsl on windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pdfKit is available for windows too, all you need to do is:

1: pip install pdfKit

2: then go to [this link](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) to download the suitable version of **wkhtmlox** needed for pdfKit to work

3: add PATH_OF_wkhtmlox/bin to your sys variable **path**

and i your python script add the folowing line:

```
pdfkit.from_url('your-url.html', 'your_pdf.pdf')
```

dont forget to `import pdfkit`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you absolutely need to convert from html but if not, you may be able to use fpdf:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

data = [
  ["hello there", 3, 12],
  ["something", 312, 66],
  ["earsfg", 303, 95],
  ["earsfg", 303, 95],
  ["earsfg", 303, 95],
]

# prepare pdf
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=18)

# write some data
for idx, line in enumerate(data):
  lineStr = "[{0}] {1}, {2}".format(line[0], line[1], line[2])
  pdf.cell(200, 8, txt=lineStr, ln=1, align="L")  

pdf.output("output.pdf")
```

There is a more in-depth tutorial [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/06/05/creating-pdfs-with-pyfpdf-and-python/)

Comment: Hi again! Could you mark one of the answers as "accepted" please ? Also, I think the question should be rephrased: It looks to me like like this has nothing to do with csv, but rather generating pdfs with python. Where you get the data from is not really relevant. I'll suggest one.